# REGEXEXTRACT to capture group of strings between 2 characters

Tags: google-sheets, nsregularexpression

I have the following working gsheet formula that transposes, split, trims using REGEXEXTRACT which works to capture the first group of strings separated by `OR`

`=transpose(split(IFERROR(TRIM(REGEXEXTRACT(A2,"([^\()]+)")))," OR ",FALSE))`

Example below using formula above

`("AD" OR "AB" OR "ZZ" OR "Short Long" OR "Long Short") w/5 (("foo bar*" OR "bar* foo" OR "kit kat*") w/5 ("ping* pong game*" OR "ppg") w/5 ("bro" OR "sis" OR "fam"))`

extracts the following for group 1

- "AD"
- "AB"
- "ZZ"
- "Short Long"
- "Long Short"

How to extract other groups that are in between `w/5` string? Note that there can be multiple instances of `w/5` from a given statement. Example above have 3.

Expected output group 2

- "foo bar*"
- "bar* foo"
- "kit kat*"

Expected output group 3

- "ping* pong game*"
- "ppg"

Expected output group 4

- "bro"
- "sis"
- "fam"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me know if this works for you!

```
=TRANSPOSE(INDEX(SPLIT(INDEX(REGEXEXTRACT(TRANSPOSE(split(A2," w/5 ",FALSE)),"([^\()]+)"))," OR ",false)))
```

[image]

Comment: This worked Martin! Thank you! This is amazing and it looks like you used INDEX which I had in mind but wasn't sure how to implement. Thanks again!